# Npm start stuck at 70% affer adding "lazy" module

Tags: angular, typescript, npm

I know it's been asked here before but no solution fixed it for me.
I've added this module to an existing project:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { DashboardComponent } from '../BackOffice/components/dashboard.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: DashboardComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
      CommonModule,
      RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  declarations: [DashboardComponent]
})
export class LazyModule { }
```

app.module:

```
 { path: 'lazy', loadChildren: 'app/lazy/lazy.module#LazyModule' },
```

Since then,  "npm start" stuck on 70%:
[image: npm start]

If I remove the module, it builds fine.
This is Angular 4 btw.
Thanks

Comment: I had a similar issue, in my case it was a 3rd party library. Have you tried debugging the build process? See this comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9779#issuecomment-394411470

Comment: Your Lazy module in not vissible in your screen shot hope it exists and it also has root component.

Comment: I follow a tutorial, and of course it exists ;) what do you mean by has a root component? any example?

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to fetch lazy module from the directory named **lazy**.

I took a look at your directory structure [here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwNKA.jpg)
But I didn't find any directory named 'lazy'.

Where does your **LazyModule** class reside?

If it is in some other directory then you can do something as below in your **AppModule**

```
 { path: 'lazy', loadChildren: './<your-deirectory-name>/lazy.module#LazyModule' },
```

Comment: it was under "lazy" directory

Comment: now I see the screenshot, I took it without the lazy dir by mistake, had to remove it in order to work on the project (because it won't compile with it)

Comment: Can you please check your angular-CLI version? Is there any difference between global angular-CLI version and your project-level angular-CLI version?